# Durandal weyland optimizations doesn't work while using multiple projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, requirejs, durandal, hottowel, weyland

My project is broken into several projects. One project is the main, and the others are for business domains.

```
Project.Main
Project.BusinessDomain1
Project.BusinessDomain2
```

As the weyland is applied to the `Project.Main` and it's the only project containing a `main.js`, the only files participate in creating `main-built.js` are those attached in `Project.Main`. As a matter of fact I want the other files to remain at their projects and load on demand by controllers later.
But the problem is that I used `Path`s in those files, which `weyland optimizer` doesn't affect them( to replace the paths with real values).

FYI, I'm using Durandal 2.0.1 and HotTowel template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things:

- If your views are dynamically generated you obviously can't package them.
- If you want to package some files and others not (such as the dynamically generated views) you can't use almond, you'd need to use the full requirejs. To do so, you need to go into the weyland config file and change almond to requirejs. Then you need to make sure that all your paths are correct at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your useful hints. Fortunately, I reached your results too and I've made the changes as you said yesterday. Hopefully your answer made me sure that I'm in correct way.