# Durandal Weyland optimizations doesn't handle the require function

Tags: javascript, requirejs, durandal, durandal-2.0, weyland

I've found out that weyland optimizer replaces the paths in the javascript files with their real values. But it doesn't replace the paths used in middle of the code using `require` function.

For example:

```
require('myscripts/mymodule', function(mymodule){
    // do something after mymodule is ready.
}
```

and I'm defined `myscripts` as a path like:

```
'myscripts': 'api/ScriptHandler/GetModule'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Durandal weyland optimizations doesn't work while using multiple projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440302/durandal-weyland-optimizations-doesnt-work-while-using-multiple-projects)

Comment: @PWKad I've created that question too. As a matter of fact, I was posting one question at first. But it was getting complicated as it addresses two totally different questions. So I decided to post them as two separate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RequireJS' optimizer needs its build file to have `findNestedDependencies: true` to find such cases. If Weyland uses RequireJS' optimizer behind the scenes (ETA: it does) this might be the solution.